# Coloured commands in iTerm

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

Previously I had a friend to set up my iTerm2 environment for me, and I got used to it. Since I changed computers, I now have to setup my environment again.

I used to use ir_black as my iTerm2 theme, and one of the functions it had was that if the command I typed is available, it turns green.

However, it seems that I am unable to replicate that even after installing new colour themes. Am I looking at a wrong direction?

Here's an image of how my terminal looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I doubt that your friend's setup has anything to do with iTerm2 color schemes. It sounds more like a shell function. E.g. check out this code for _zsh_: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users//2010/msg00709.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `man ls` has additional information on color listings.

Using the `-G` flag with `ls` ought to enable colour, if your shell's $TERM environment is set to a colour-capable value.

To have colour listings be the default of `ls`, the `CLICOLOR` environment variable can be set (to anything, even '') in the appropriate login script file.

It's either done like this:

`CLICOLOR=''; export CLICOLOR`

or

`setenv CLICOLOR`

depending on what login shell you use.

---

### For interactive as-you-type colourizations...

There are quite a few add-ons for the `zsh` shell.  A google search on "color completion zsh" will return dozens of articles on how to set up coloured prompts and file-completion.

I did come across a reference to `fish`, a [Friendly Interactive Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell).  I installed it on my Mac, and it appears to work as you've indicated.

If `which fish` gives a `Command not found` error, you'll have to install it from the [official fish homepage.](http://fishshell.com)

Comment: actually what I am referring to is the command itself. Note how `ll` is in green, note white, and also my git is in red (because there's changes). If I type in an invalid command, say, `cf`, it will appear as red not green

Comment: What login shell do you use?

Comment: I am using iTerm2. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: show me the output from this command:

tty ; ps

Comment: Does this help? http://imgur.com/ZrvTRmF

Comment: Your login shell is /bin/zsh for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the `zsh` shell this is what you are looking for: [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting).